# Using AMPScript to extract text from a String after nth delimiter

Tags: substring, ampscript

I need to be able to extract from a string after nth delimiter.
In this case, the delimiter is an ***underscore***.

The challenge is that the last delimiter could be in the 2nd, 3rd,4th or 5th position

**Example**:

1. LB_AB_BookingReminder_123-1-2-1S (3rd position)
2. LB_AB_123-1-2-1S (2nd position)
3. LB_AB_Booking_Reminder_123-1-2-1S (4th position)

**Output Needed**: 123-1-2-1S

Thank You

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [RegExMatch()](https://ampscript.guide/regexmatch) function may be your best bet:

```ampscript
%%[

set @pattern = "^.+_(.+\-\d+\-\d+\-.+)"
set @s1 = "LB_AB_BookingReminder_123-1-2-1S"
set @s2 = "LB_AB_BookingReminder_123-1-2-1S"
set @s3 = "LB_AB_Booking_Reminder_123-1-2-1S"

set @match1 = RegExMatch(@s1, @pattern, 1)
set @match2 = RegExMatch(@s2, @pattern, 1)
set @match3 = RegExMatch(@s3, @pattern, 1)

]%%
<br>%%=v(@match1)=%%
<br>%%=v(@match2)=%%
<br>%%=v(@match3)=%%
```

Output:

```
123-1-2-1S
123-1-2-1S
123-1-2-1S
```

Regex101 snippet: https://regex101.com/r/DJeKjd/1

AMPscript tester: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/F4WISQvc